# formatting text using hovertemplate in plotly

Tags: plotly

I'm building a feature with `plotly`, in particular a scatterplot. I would like that when the point is reached, it shows the mean value `x` and its standard deviation `xstd`. I have tried with the following:

```
        x = df['col1']
        
        y =df['col2']
        
        xstd = df['col3']
        
        ystd = df['col4']

        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, 
                                 y=y,
                                 mode='markers+text',
                                 text=formulas,
                                 hovertemplate=
                                 '<i>Var 1</i>: %{x:.2f} +- %{xstd:.2f}</i>'+
                                 '<br>Var 2: %{y:.2f}'+
                                 '<br>%{text}</br>'),
                                 row=1,col=1,
                                 )
```

but it actually it's not formatted well, everything after `%{x:.2f}` is reported as it is in the plot. What should I do to add the rest into formatting?

Comment: In the html code, the `'` before the first join is missing. Also, the start of the italic is missing. `'<i>Var 1</i>: %{x:.2f}' + '<i>%{xstd:.2f}</i>'+ '<br>Var 2: %{y:.2f}'+ '<br>%{text}</br>')`

Comment: that wasn't supposed to be a join but a way to state a 'plus / minus'. I've tried to correct the start of italic but still encounter the same issue.

Comment: I understand that xstd is custom data, and I've done this configuration, but it doesn't improve the situation. `'<i>Var 1: %{x:.2f} +- %{customdata:.2f}</i>'`